# lisp, how to eliminate restarts

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am quite new to lisp. When I was playing in clisp environment I made mistakes often but was then immediately punished by a long list like

```
ABORT          :R11     Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R12     Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R13     Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R14     Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R15     Abort debug loop
```

which just ruins my screen and I cannot see any previous commands. Does anyone know how to eliminate this prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to all the other excellent answers, here is [a way to avoid landing in the debugger](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/restarts.html#global-handler) (a la scheme):

```
(set-global-handler 'error 'sys::abortonerror)
```

This is **NOT** recommended, learn [the debugger](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/repl.html) instead!

E.g., use `:q` to escape from all the debuggers to the top level REPL.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you have been hitting errors, dropping into the debugger, and continuing to work, piling up nested debuggers. You should choose an appropriate restart to end debugging whenever you are done with examining the error. I don't recall what the quick keystrokes for that are in CLISP, but presumably jokester's answer has that.

Answer (score 0):

in `gnu clisp` and linux, you can use `ctrl-D` to leave it and go back

if you are using windows version and that doesn't work, try `ctrl-Z <enter>`\

btw many interactive interpreters can understand that.

Comment: Thank you, and it works! By the way, do you know some method that I can use to remove them in batch?

Comment: not heard of that, and I don't think it's a good idea to jump off a series of error message at a time. maybe you will feel better when you get used to the REPL loop.